# Palce to put non generic helper functions for views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, view-helpers

I am a beginner on rails. While writing one of the views in my applications I end up with big chunk(~100 lines) of ugly code. Its fairly non generic as it mostly consist of some conditional look up to a view specific constant hash. I want to remove this ugly chunk of code out of the view file.

What would be the best place to put this piece of code? Specifically, are helper modules right place for such non-generic code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`, it will then be accessible by any view rendered with the `application` layout.

Another option is to define a *custom* helper module, one which is not necessarily associated with a given view or controller (See the video I linked below), and `include` it in the modules of the view/controllers you wish to have that functionality in.

Helper modules are indeed to place to call them but be careful how you declare your methods, there are limitations to what you are able to define in a helper module.

[Here](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/designing-helpers-in-ruby-on-rails/) is a good article outlining helper modules from *May, 2011*

[Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/64-custom-helper-modules/) is is a RailsCast outlining *custom* helper modules (i.e. custom as in modules not necessarily associated with a given controller or view).  Short, sweet, and to the point.

Comment: I knew about the application helper or custom helpers. But but question is: Are helpers the right place to put such **non-generic** code which will not be used by other views of my application.

Comment: @Dee This is not something that is black and white. But, from what you have described it sounds like this is code that is obtrusive to stick in your `application_controller.rb` and it is not code with functionality which justifies it's own controller, the most effective and efficient option may be to create a custom helper module and include it in the helpers you wish to have that functionality.  That said, this is ultimately a judgement call which the designer of the application (i.e. _you_) needs to decide upon.